# How to Change the Default Sort Order of Bars in Apex Charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, apexcharts

I am using React Apex-Charts to build a horizontal Bar Chart which currently looks like this:
[image]
I want to change the default sort order to be descending not Ascending such that the bar with the highest value is at the top while the smallest value is at the bottom. How do I accomplish this?
The following is my current code:

```js
       <Chart
          type='bar'
          height={550}
          series= {[{
            name: "Transaction",
            data: [4000, 4300, 4408, 4700, 5400, 5800, 6900, 11000, 12000, 13800],
          }]}
          
          options={{
            title:{ text:"Top 10 Schools By Transactions",     style: { fontSize: 25 , fontFamily: "IBM Plex Sans", fontWeight:700}, },
            colors: ["#295fab"],
            yaxis: {

              labels: {
                formatter: (val) => {
                  return `${val}`;
                },
                style: {fontWeight:500, fontSize: "15", colors: ["#000"], fontFamily:"IBM Plex Sans", },
              },
            },        
            xaxis: {
        
              categories: ["Jomo Kenyatta Univerity", "Technical Univaersity of Kenya", "University of Nairobi", "Kenyatta University", "Moi University", "Masinde Muliro University", "Maasai Mara University", "Maseno University", "Laikipia University", 
            ],
              labels:{
                formatter: (val) => {
                  return `$${val}`;
                },
                style: {fontSize: "14",fontWeight:500, colors: ["#000"], fontFamily:"IBM Plex Sans"  },
              }
            },
            noData: {
              text: "Loading...",
            },
            chart: {
              fontFamily: 'IBM Plex Sans',
              toolbar: {
                tools: {
                  download: true,
                  selection: false,
                  zoom: false,
                  zoomin: false,
                  zoomout: false,
                  pan: false,
                  reset: false | '<img src="/static/icons/reset.png" width="20">',
                  customIcons: []
                },
              },
         
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              formatter: function (val) {
                return  `$${val}`;
              },
              offsetX: 40,
            
              style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                colors: ["#304758"],
              }
            },
            plotOptions: {
              bar: {
                borderRadius: 16,
                horizontal: true,
                dataLabels: {
                  position: 'top', // top, center, bottom
                },
              }
            },
            legend:{         
              fontSize: "16px",
              fontFamily: "IBM Plex Sans"
            }


        }}
          >
          </Chart>
```

Comment: reverse the order of the data? --> `[4000, 4300, 4408, 4700, 5400, 5800, 6900, 11000, 12000, 13800]` -- to -- `[13800, 12000, 11000, 6900, 5800, 5400, 4700, 4408, 4300, 4000]` -- but don't forget to adjust `xaxis.categories`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reverse prototype: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

```
var data = [4000, 4300, 4408, 4700, 5400, 5800, 6900, 11000, 12000, 13800];
var categories = ["Jomo Kenyatta Univerity", "Technical Univaersity of Kenya", "University of Nairobi", "Kenyatta University", "Moi University", "Masinde Muliro University", "Maasai Mara University", "Maseno University", "Laikipia University"];

var reversed_data = data.reverse();
var reversed_cat = categories.reverse();
```